# Multiple hidden menus that open and close using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/tw6sdod9/

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('li ul').slideUp(0);

    $('.no-js li a').on("click", function() {
      $('ul#inner-li ul').slideUp(400);
      if ($(this).siblings('ul').is(":visible"))
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp(400);
      else
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown(400);
    });
  });
  $('#nav li a').on('click', function() {
    $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
  });





  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('li ul#inner-li-texts').slideDown(0);

    $('.no-js li a#texts').on("click", function() {
      $('ul ul').slideUp(400);
      if ($(this).siblings('ul').is(":visible"))
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp(400);
      else
        $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown(400);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="no-js">
  <li class="caps"><a href="#">Works</a>
    <ul id="inner-li">
      <li><a href="blog.html">blog</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="portraits.html">Portraits</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="paintings.html">Paintings</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="drawings.html">Drawings</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="photography.html">Photography</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="caps"><a id="texts" href="#">Texts</a>
    <ul id="inner-li-texts">
      <li><a class="current" href="#essay-one">Essay one</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#essay-two">Essay two</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#essay-three">Essay three</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="caps"><a href="../news.htm">News</a>
  </li>
  <li class="caps"><a href="../biography.htm">Biography</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

On this fiddle there is a menu with two sub-menus hidden under the 'Works' and 'Text' links.

What I am trying to achieve is this:

1. On load I want the text sub menu open and the works menu closed.
2. When the users clicks on either link the sub menu to that link opens or closes.

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('li ul').slideUp(0);

      $('.no-js li a').on("click", function () {
        $('ul#inner-li ul').slideUp(400);
        if($(this).siblings('ul').is(":visible"))
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp(400);
        else
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown(400);
       });
    });
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: If you click the second time on texts the bug appears. (It opens and close immediately)

Comment: Using a `.no-js` selector in jQuery. The irony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add two times a click-listener for your menu.

I updated the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tw6sdod9/2/)

Just removed the duplicated code and added:

```
jQuery('#texts').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tw6sdod9/3/)

HTML

```
<ul class="no-js">
  <li class="caps"><a class="alink" href="#">Works</a>
      <ul class="cls" id="inner-li">
                <li><a href="blog.html">blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="portraits.html">Portraits</a></li>
                <li><a href="paintings.html">Paintings</a></li>
                <li><a href="drawings.html">Drawings</a></li>
                <li><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></li>

      </ul></li>
      <li class="caps"><a id="texts" class="alink" href="#">Texts</a>
      <ul class="cls" id="inner-li-texts">
                <li><a class="current" href="#essay-one">Essay one</a></li>
                <li><a href="#essay-two">Essay two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#essay-three">Essay three</a></li>
               </ul>
                </li>
  <li class="caps"><a class="alink" href="../news.htm">News</a></li>
  <li class="caps"><a class="alink" href="../biography.htm">Biography</a></li>

  </ul>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.cls').slideUp(0);

    $('a.alink').on("click", function () {
        $(this).next("ul.cls").slideToggle(400);       
    });
});
```

Worked for me

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Why were you adding a second click handler to `#texts`?  There's one click handler here:

```
$('.no-js li a').on("click", function () {
    //...
});
```

But then there's another one here:

```
$('.no-js li a#texts').on("click", function () {
    //...
});
```

So while clicking on any other menu invokes only the first handler, clicking on `#texts` invokes *both*.  It looks like [you only want the first](http://jsfiddle.net/tw6sdod9/1/).